# Export object inside of function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to write functional stateless components and in doing so have run into an issue. I wrap by `Navigator` in a function that takes props as an argument (*these are arbitrary*). The component that gets wrapped is currently defined as follows since it is used in the reducer for this component.

```
export const Navigator = StackNavigator(screens, navigatorConfig);

const NavigatorView = (props) => {
    return (<Navigator screenProps={{ ...props }}/>);
};
```

This works, but I'd ideally like to be able to instantiate the `Navigator` as a local variable in the `NavigatorView` function, and export there so that I have flexibility towards what attributes I can set at instantiation time (*like shown below*).

```
const NavigatorView = (myArg, props) => {
    const Navigator = StackNavigator(screens, myArg);
    return (<Navigator screenProps={{ ...props }}/>);
};
```

The problem here is as follows, how can I export `Navigator` (*that's used in the reducer*) while keeping it wrapped in a function? I've tried `module.exports = Navigator;`, `export const Navigator...` but they do not work. Thanks.

Comment: `let Navigator = null;` (outside of the `NavigatorView`) & `Navigator = StackNavigator(screens, myArg)` inside the `NavigatorView`?

Comment: This would work except that the `Navigator` is exported to the `reducer`, so it's being used in two places, in this module, and in the `reducer`.

Answer (score 2):

How about making a function that returns a function?

```
export const generateNavigator = (screens, navigatorConfig) => 
  StackNavigator(screens, navigatorConfig);

const NavigatorView = (myArg, props) => {
    const Navigator = generateNavigator(screens, myArg);
    return (<Navigator screenProps={{ ...props }}/>);
};
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting approach. But since the `Navigator` is used in two places, in the `reducer`, and also in the module itself, it needs to be the same reference. The perfect solution would involve being able to wrap the the `StackNavigator` in the function; so I could pass it arguments, then export it.